# Listar todas as páginas que o usuário administra

Tags: facebook, api

Atualmente utilizo da seguinte forma para obter determinada página que o usuário administra:

```
$graphObject = $response->getDecodedBody();
$fbUserName  = $graphObject['name'];
$fbUserEmail = $graphObject['email'];
$fbUserID    = $graphObject['id'];
$pages       = $graphObject['accounts'];
// Obtendo determinada página, onde "0" é o numero da página no json:
$singlePage  = $pages['data']['0'];
$pageName    = $singlePage['name'];
$pagetoken = $singlePage['access_token'];
$pageCategory= $singlePage['category'];
$pageID = $singlePage['id'];
```

porém eu gostaria de obter todas as páginas e monta um array com os dados de cada página, nome,id,accesstoken e depois imprimir somente o nome de cada página de forma que fique uma lista, se alguém puder me ajudar desde já agradeço a atenção.

Comment: Dessa forma vc só uma página?

Comment: Preciso que me retorne a lista de todos os grupos que o usuario administra e pegar o nome e id de cada fanpage e imprimir somente o nome de cada pagina.